# WHERE clause failed

Tags: php, sql

Can anyone please help me with my code?

I have a table in the database named "Date" with a field name "mydate", and it contains the following data

```
2011-02-02 00:00:00
2011-01-02 00:00:00
2010-03-02 00:00:00
2010-01-03 00:00:00
2008-03-03 00:00:00
2008-02-03 00:00:00
```

Then i create query and get its result

```
$result=mysql_query("select DATE(mydate) as Date, subject, update_id, description, image from news ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 3")or die (mysql_error());
```

As you can see, I only get 3 data from the $result. Now, when i reach the last row from the $result, I store it in a session named "$_SESSION['val']".
So, the value of $_SESSION['val'] is 2010-03-02 00:00:00

After that, I store that session into "$val_date" and create a query. This is my code:

```
$val_date = $_SESSION['val'];

    $result=mysql_query("select DATE(mydate) as Date, subject, update_id, description, image from news WHERE Date < $val_date  ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 3")or die (mysql_error());

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

The problem is, $count=0 it should be $count = 3 because it will read the following data according to the query:

```
2010-01-03 00:00:00
2008-03-03 00:00:00
2008-02-03 00:00:00
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I can see mysqli-fan trolls coming :D

Comment: Please do not use reserve keyword, the column should not `date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query would probably fail because you forgot to put the string delimiter (single quotes) to the date in the mysql string.

```
mysql_query("select DATE(date) as Date, subject, update_id, description, image from news WHERE Date < '$val_date'  ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 3");
```

But you should use PDO or mysqli instead of the old an deprecated mysql extenstion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you state your column is named mydate but you write date?

Try this

```
$result=mysql_query("select DATE(mydate) as Date, subject, update_id, description, 
image from news ORDER BY mydate DESC LIMIT 3")or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Ok, then disregard this answer. Maybe answer from @andreashager would fix it.